# SQL UPDATE broken

Tags: php, sql

I have been troubleshooting this code for awhile, but it won't work and I can't find out why. Does anyone see an error? Also, I'm aware that there is no `WHERE` statement, I intentionally want to update all records.

```
<?php
// Connect to database
$link = mysqli_connect('*****', '*****', '*****'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 
} 
mysqli_select_db(bullseye);

// Varaible setting
$header = $_POST['header'];
$video = $_POST['video'];
$m_title = $_POST['m_title'];
$m_sub = $_POST['m_sub'];
$w_title = $_POST['w_title'];
$w_sub = $_POST['w_sub'];
$w_t1 = $_POST['w_t1'];
$w_t2 = $_POST['w_t2'];
$w_t3 = $_POST['w_t3'];
$w_d1 = $_POST['w_d1'];
$w_d2 = $_POST['w_d2'];
$w_d3 = $_POST['w_d3'];
$p_title = $_POST['p_title'];
$p_sub = $_POST['p_sub'];

    mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE tbl_name SET 
    header=$header, 
    video=$video, 
    mtitle=$m_title, 
    msub=$m_sub, 
    wtitle=$w_title, 
    wsub=$w_sub, 
    wt1=$w_t1, 
    wt2=$w_t2, 
    wt3=$w_t3, 
    wd1=$w_d1 
    wd2=$w_d2, 
    wd3=$w_d3, 
    ptitle=$p_title, 
    psub=$p_sub");
?>
```

EDIT:

```
mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE about SET 
    header='$header', 
    video='$video', 
    mtitle='$m_title', 
    msub='$m_sub', 
    wtitle='$w_title', 
    wsub='$w_sub', 
    wt1='$w_t1', 
    wt2='$w_t2', 
    wt3='$w_t3', 
    wd1='$w_d1', 
    wd2='$w_d2', 
    wd3='$w_d3', 
    ptitle='$p_title', 
    psub='$p_sub'");
```

Comment: Your UPDATE has no WHERE?

Comment: I know that the code is can be hacked, I just want to get it working before I sanitize the input.

Comment: Do it right the first time. That's how the cool devs do it.

Comment: @773 Use PDO, with placeholders. The reason you're getting interpolation issues is the very same reason SQL injection can exist.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh added a solution of that.

Comment: @Pachonk: No, you didn't. Wow that's still very bad.

Comment: Redundant question and *terrible* accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should prepare it using MySQLi as to protect yourself from MySQL injection:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "bullseye");
$query = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE tbl_name SET 
        header=?, 
        video=?, 
        mtitle=?, 
        msub=?, 
        wtitle=?, 
        wsub=?, 
        wt1=?, 
        wt2=?, 
        wt3=?, 
        wd1=? 
        wd2=?, 
        wd3=?, 
        ptitle=?, 
        psub=?");

$query->bind_param("ssssssssssssss, $header, $video, $m_title, $m_sub, $w_title, $w_t1, $w_t2, $w_t3, $w_d1, $w_d2, $w_d3, $p_title, $p_sub");

$query->execute();

$query->close();

$mysqli->close();
```

This code should work. If it doesn't please post the error.

Comment: @Pachonk Please don't encourage approaches vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @Pachonk, is a 'where' statement REQUIRED? I want to update all the records.

Comment: You want to make every row identical?

Comment: @Pachonk, with the quotes around the database name, it won't work

Comment: Why don't you attempt to use the bottom solution. It will protect you much better, plus the `MySQL` extension is deprecated. You should be using the MySQLi extension.

Comment: I'll try it now. FYI, you forgot the ending quote when you bound the parameters.

Comment: Okay. Are all your variables strings?

Comment: Ouch this is a mess. Why are you using this (presumably valid -- I'll take your word for it) string-based (therefore interpolation manipulable) version of `bind_param`? Please stop encouraging use of MySQLi. Instead encourage PDO with placeholders & array-based binding.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you need to concat your query with your variables. And not just a big string.

Comment: Nope, the double quote still enables php to parse variables inside

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following to chose your database:

```
mysqli_select_db($link, "bullseye");
```